# Wait before next function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to wait 5 seconds before running the second line:

```js
function waitnext() {
    setTimeout('', 5000);
    alert('waited');
}
```

However it seems to open the alert instantly when the function is run. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Write alert inside the callback

Answer (score 0):

```js
function waitnext() {
   setTimeout( function(){
       alert('waited');
   }, 5000); 
}

waitnext();
```

Your syntax is wrong. Here you go with the documentation **https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp**

Answer (score 0):

Put the line you want to run after some delay as a callback of `setTimeout`

```
function waitnext() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('waited'); // runs after 5000ms
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` evaluates a callback function after a specified number of milliseconds has elapsed.

Solution using ES6.

```js
let waitnext = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // callback
    alert('waited');
  }, 5000);
}
waitnext();
```

Or using ES5:

```js
'use strict';

var waitnext = function waitnext() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    // callback
    alert('waited');
  }, 5000);
};
waitnext();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function waitnext(){
 setTimeout(function(){
 alert('waited');
}, 5000);
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

a few samples ...

```
 var myAlarm = e => console.log(e);
 var myStop = () => console.log('stop');
 var wait = (delay, callback) => setTimeout(callback, delay);

 wait(2000, () => myAlarm("finished after 2 seconds"));
 wait(3000, myStop);

 // the following line don´t work ...
 // the function was executed immediately
 wait(4000, myAlarm('cheesecake'));

//use setTimeout 
setTimeout(myStop, 1000);
// the following line don´t work ...
// the function was executed immediately
setTimeout(myAlarm('cheesecake'),3000);
// this works
setTimeout(() => myAlarm('cheesecake'),3000);
```